# Get a Static property from a class generic, where Interface contains the property name

Tags: c#

When you have a function:

```cs
public interface IHasName
{
    static string Name { get; }
}

//class{
public static string GetName<T>() where T : IHasName
{
    return T.Name;
}
//}
```

This is not working, only when I change the static to public and I create a `new T()`.
The usage have to be like:

```cs
public class Model: IHasName
{
    public static string Name => "Niek";
}

var name = GetName<Model>();
```

Do you have the solution that sill use a static property through a Generic.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lets take a step back, why do you need this? What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? How do you intend to use it and why?

Comment: I need this because it has a POCO with a FileName property. That I need to call to get a json content from what is the POCO content.
So the call will be for example: `var data = JsonHelper.Read<PocoModel>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available as a [preview feature in .NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/), and will probably be properly released in .NET 7:

```
public interface IHasName
{
    public static abstract string Name { get; }
}

public class Model : IHasName
{
    public static string Name => "Foo";
}

class Foo
{
    public static string GetName<T>() where T : IHasName
    {
        return T.Name;
    }
}
```

See it on [dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aCovrU).

Comment: Thanks, you have also the solution for .NET 5?

Comment: @niektuytel No, this is only introduced as a preview feature in .NET 6